# Loop wait for intent result (Java Android)

Tags: java, android

I am really really really new to this so dont laugh too hard... or talk too cryptically...
I have searched and experimented and searched etc... i am learning, but i am getting more confused as well!

I need to loop through a folder on the sdcard and send each instance of any .html files in that folder via android intents one by one, once each has sucessfully processed/printer by another android app. Let's Print Droid (a great printing app for Network attached printers). 
This app can only accept one file, process that file render it etc then send it to the printer and then it sends back via intents the result good or bad!

I have tried various sleep options (bad practice i know!) and wait and notify (better i believe?) but i can't get it to print more than the first it finds or last file (depending on my code!)

Below is one version of my code. This version sends the first file it processes via "Lets Print Driod" app, then continues to loop though showing my Toast message "Waiting loop number --> ".

Can anyone show me the correct way to use wait and notify once the intent result is received in my loop ?

Many thanks for any help.

```
package com.my.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String received_results_from_LPD = "YES";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            print_all_html();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }


    public synchronized void print_all_html() throws InterruptedException {
        received_results_from_LPD = "YES";

        for(int x = 1; x < 6; x = x+1) {
        if (received_results_from_LPD == "YES") {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setClassName("com.blackspruce.lpd","com.blackspruce.lpd.WebPrint");
        i.setData( Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/test" + x + ".html"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loop Position " + x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value of LPD " + received_results_from_LPD, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Printing " + "test" + x + ".html", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        received_results_from_LPD = "NO"; //reset for next time
        startActivityForResult(i, 99);
        //wait();
        }
        else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Waiting loop number --> " + x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        received_results_from_LPD = "NO";
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected synchronized void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null && requestCode == 99 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //successful 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        received_results_from_LPD = "YES";
        //notify();
    }
    else {
        //not successful
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oopps!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        received_results_from_LPD = "YES";
        //notify();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Sort of fixed it...bodged it?!? Not exactly what i hoped but prints for the time being until i understand Java better!

Comment: Well, you can hold on to the list of pending files and issue the next one from onActivityResult.

Comment: Essentially, you must turn your loop inside out - instead of the loop "driving" the program flow, you need a loop made by deciding what to do each time program flow enters your code through an event method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't 'bad' it's just that you cannot loop like that, since start activity is not blocking. I would drop the for and test if I still have data to process in the onActivityResult.